# Mysql ON DUPLICATE UPDATE error - multiple columns with calculations

Tags: mysql

Suppose I want to update two columns in one ON DUPLICATE STATEMENT:

```
 INSERT INTO `daily_lead_rollups` (`year`, `month`, `day`, `a_id`, `f_id`, `0_d`,`0_r`) VALUES (NEW.year,NEW.month,NEW.day,NEW.a_id,NEW.f_id, 1,NEW.payout) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    0_d  =  0_d + 1,   0_r  =0_r + NEW.payout;
```

Error:

1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

I know you can insert multiple rows, but I didn't find anything about updating multiple columns with a calculation.

MySQL is fine with one calculation, even without

> VALUES

, but has an issue with two!

I corrected the statement for future reference, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are trying to `VALUES` like that, but I suspect you mean this:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    0_d = 0_d + 1,
    0_r = 0_r + NEW.payout
```

There are also some good examples of how to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I meant but it still does not seem to work (got the same error). Originally I just had 0_d = 0_d + 1. I will look at the manual again...

Comment: @Len: Are you sure that the problem isn't exactly what the error message says: that you are trying to create a trigger on a table that already has one?

Comment: This trigger is actually auto generated with many sets of hour rollups, based on another dependency and another dependency...you are absolutely correct - I was off by one letter in the drop trigger statement....Sometimes you don't see the obvious after a 12 hours!

Comment: One last thing, the VALUE statement caused null errors for some reason, it works great in the simplest form without VALUE.